# Python ibm_db Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL4917N Element "SQLE_CLIENT_INFO_WRKSTNNAME" in the option array is not valid. SQLCODE=-4917

Tags: python, db2, db2-luw

I get the following error when trying to connect to db2 using the ibm_db python package.

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL4917N  Element "SQLE_CLIENT_INFO_WRKSTNNAME" 
in the option array is not valid. SQLCODE=-4917
```

This problem is specific to my new machine (2019 MacBook Pro).  I set up this machine from a Time Machine backup of my old machine (Late 2013 MacBook Pro).  The exact same code is able to connect to the database without error on my old machine.  The new machine can connect to the database using the SQLDeveloper program but not python.

The error persists when trying different databases on different servers.  I am trying to connect to the Db2 Warehouse on Cloud service.

Environment:

- 2019 MacBook Pro
- macOS v. 10.14.6
- python v. 3.6.8 (also tried 3.7.4)
- ibm_db v. 3.0.1
- conda environment (also tried non-conda python)

I've tried:

- Uninstall / reinstall ibm_db with pip (regular and sudo, --no-cache-dir)
- Download clidriver to different directory and set IBM_DB_HOME env var

I get the error when executing the connect method:

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect(CONN_STRING, "", "")
```

At this point, I expect python to connect to the database, but I get the following error:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL4917N  Element "SQLE_CLIENT_INFO_WRKSTNNAME" 
in the option array is not valid. SQLCODE=-4917
```

db2level command

```
~/anaconda3/envs/ibm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clidriver/bin/db2level
```

db2level output

```
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "*") uses
"64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10055" with level identifier "0606010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.0.5", "special_35187", "DARWIN64105_35187",
and Fix Pack "5".
Product is installed at
"~/anaconda3/envs/ibm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clidriver".
```

Comment: Sounds like a driver version mismatch; what version of the Db2 driver have you installed?

Comment: @mao The DSN is correct.  I've also tried a different database on a different server, and I get the same error.

Comment: @mustaccio From `~/anaconda3/envs/ibm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db-3.0.1.dist-info/METADATA` I see version 3.0.1.  Is this the correct way to check the driver version?

Comment: @GCannon  focus on the CLI driver then. You could also Edit your question to add these facts (instead of adding them in comments):  Db2-server details (platform + version), CLI driver version/fixpack detail (what filename did you download) , and whether you can use the DSN at the bash command line (if you have the Db2 clp in your Db2-client), or if the `db2cli` command exists in your Db2-client can you validate the connection with it etc. If your Db2-client has the `db2level` program, show its output in the question also.

Comment: @mao I have added the db2level output to the question. I see db2cli, but it is telling me all my commands are malformed.  I see the same db2cli behavior on the machine with working ibm_db, so I do not the db2cli behavior indicates the issue I'm facing.

Comment: @GCannon please edit your question to add the other facts I mentioned in my previous comment.  To validate the DSN connection with CLI use:  `db2cli validate -dsn X -connect -user Y -passwd Z`. Your Db2 client is a bit old, current version is 11.5 , but that might not be the problem. Compare the working and failing db2cli.ini and db2dsdriver.cfg files. Compare the shell environment variables likewise.

Comment: @GCannon for Db2 Warehouse on Cloud, the dashboard lets you download the ODBC and CLI driver that should match your cloud Db2-instance version(s). Validate the DSN as above and compare the two config files and environment variable values.

Comment: @GCannon  your restored TimeMachine backup may still have the old hostname somewhere, and if that differs from the new hostname of your new 2019-Macbook-pro and is somehow getting passed to the Db2-client then your symptom may appear. Hence the suggestion to compare the configs.

Comment: I have edited my question to replace DSN with CONN_STRING, as this is how I am making the connection.  Having a DSN specified in the db2cli.ini file is not required to make connections with python, but it was needed to use the db2cli. I also noticed that the downloads from the Db2 on Cloud dashboard currently have an older driver version than the pip install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClientWrkStnName had an invalid character as @mao and @kkuduk suggested.  This resulted from the conflict of Mac ComputerName between my old Mac and new Mac on the same network.  Ex. Gray's MacBook Pro -> Gray's MacBook Pro (2).  The issue is resolved by changing ComputerName and HostName on the new computer from the terminal.

```
scutil --set ComputerName "graymac"
scutil --set HostName "graymac"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that there was an attempt to set an invalid value for SQLE_CLIENT_INFO_WRKSTNNAME. 
Db2 cloud should accept a value up to 255 bytes and it should default to the current hostname, so maybe there is some invalid character returned by gethostbyname? 
To confirm that we would have to collect db2cli trace during the execution (to see actual value that it attempts to set).

The simplest Python code to test is to run

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("SAMPLE","db2v111","passw0rd")
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,"select CURRENT client_wrkstnname  from sysibm.sysdummy1")
ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt)
```

for me connections works fine and it returns my current hostname:

```
In [6]: ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt)
Out[6]: (u'kkuduk',)
```

A workaround for you to test is to put some other value in the db2cli.ini, e.g. if I would set:

```
cat /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/clidriver/cfg/db2cli.ini
[sample]
port=60111
hostname=localhost
database=sample
ClientWrkStnName=OverridenHostname
```

the same code returns:

```
In [4]: ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt)
Out[4]: (u'OverridenHostname',)
```

Comment: Adding a db2cli.ini file to clidriver/config file with the ClientWrkStnName override is a valid workaround.  I also discovered that adding CLIENTWRSTNNAME=FOO to the connection string accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Yes, the basic point was *not* to pass the invalid value. I'm still curious what was the value it tried to pass though - I tried multiple random values with special characters, non-ASCII characters and never got SQL4917N.
Also, I suggest to mark one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: The previous ComputerName value was "Gray's MBP"